# VirtualBox - Allow Host-Only client to claim only specific IP address

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Is there any way to allow VM, which is using VirtualBox's "Host-Only Adapter", to claim only specific IP address? I tried to use this:

```bash
VBoxManage dhcpserver modify --network HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0 --mac-address="080027DE7ECC" --fixed-address="192.168.56.100"
```

It only declares default IP address for MAC-address, but VM still can use any IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Also, the `VBoxManage dhcpserver modify` command that you gave does not declare a default IP address. It tells the VirtualBox DHCP server to offer 192.168.56.100 when 080027DE7ECC makes a DHCP request.

Comment: That's sad. Anyway, thank you